# iptables snat does not change source IP

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am on ubuntu (with IP 10.0.0.1) trying to snat packets going out from port 9090. I want to change the source IP to 10.0.0.2

I have added the following rule through iptables:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 --protocol TCP --source-port 9090 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2:9090

# sudo iptables -t nat -vL
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2432 packets, 162K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere        tcp spt:9090 to:10.0.0.2:9090
```

However, this didn't change the source IP address. Through tcpdump, I could see the source IP on the outgoing packets was 10.0.0.1.

Note that 10.0.0.2 is assigned to a different machine.

My questions are: (1) I am not sure if the packets are hitting this rule. What's a good way to verify the packets are indeed hitting this rule. (2) Is there anything else I need to execute/enable to get SNAT to work (perhaps chaining?).

Thanks!

Comment: The proper parameter is `--to-source`. Are you sure your rule is even active? Please post the output of `iptables -t nat -vL`.

Comment: Just delete your comment and update the question instead. You’ll even get some additional attention as a side effect. ;) I’ll look into it later.

Comment: Well, as you can see, no packet is ever hitting the rule. Are you sure your packets match the criteria? Namely: Leaving though `eth0`, TCP, source port (not destination!) 9090 (which I personally find very unlikely for regular software).

Comment: Thanks @DanielB. Well, I have a server (IP 10.0.0.1) running on port 9090. When it receives a SYN from a client, I want the SYN-ACK to go out with src IP:port as 10.0.0.2:9090. Through tcpdump, I see the SYN-ACK go out with 10.0.0.1:9090

Comment: BTW - removing -o eth0 didnt help. :-(

Comment: maybe there's a hidden MASQUERADE somewhere in your chain.

Comment: "_I have a server running on port 9090_" - the listening port is not the same as the connected port... check `netstat -nlpt`

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks @DanielB. Well, I have a server (IP 10.0.0.1) running on port 9090. When it receives a SYN from a client, I want the SYN-ACK to go out with src IP:port as 10.0.0.2:9090. Through tcpdump, I see the SYN-ACK go out with 10.0.0.1:9090

I don't think there is a way to achieive what you want with iptables NAT (and if you did I don't think it would be useful, clients will reject packets from unexpected IPs)

iptables NAT works on *connections*, only the first packet of each connection is subject to the user-visible NAT tables. Later packets are translated (or not) according to the connection tracking entries established by the first packet.